# Xamarin - Detect correct or incorrect pin on phone unlock event

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin. I want to be able to detect incorrect/correct password when the user tries to login on his phone(device level, not on an application). I tried DeviceAdminReceiver class, but it does not trigger OnPasswordFailed/OnPasswordSucceeded method. Please see the code below :

Receiver

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
    [Android.Runtime.Register("android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver", DoNotGenerateAcw = true)]
    public class LoginWatcher : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "OnReceive",
            ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

        public void OnDisabled(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "OnDisabled",
            ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }


        public void OnEnabled(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "OnEnabled",
            ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

        public void OnPasswordChanged(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "OnPasswordChanged",
            ToastLength.Long).Show(); 
        }

        public void OnPasswordExpiring(Context context, Intent intent)
        { 
            Toast.MakeText(context, "OnPasswordExpiring",
            ToastLength.Long).Show(); 
        }

        public void OnPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "OnPasswordFailed", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }


        public void OnPasswordSucceeded(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "OnPasswordSucceeded", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
```

Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".LoginWatcher" android:label="@string/sample_device_admin" android:description="@string/sample_device_admin_description" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" android:resource="@drawable/device_policies" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_EXPIRING" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
```

Policies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-policies>
    <limit-password />
    <watch-login />
    <reset-password />
    <force-lock />
    <wipe-data />
    <expire-password />
    <encrypted-storage />
    <disable-camera />
    <disable-keyguard-features />
  </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you want to implement a custom PIN login in your app?  Or do you mean a device level login?  Your question as written is vague and broad.

Comment: @Jasonj a device level login.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a **DeviceAdminReceiver** that will be notified about failed password attempts, as well as a successful password attempt that occurred after a failed attempt. This is covered in the [documentation of Android's device administration APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

Note that the user will have to agree to allow your app to serve as a device administrator, via the Settings app, before you will get these events.
[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DeviceAdmin/PasswordEnforcer) demonstrates listening for those events, plus setting up a password quality policy.

Here is the same thread that you can take a look:
[Xamarin MonoAndroid DeviceAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679322/xamarin-monoandroid-deviceadmin)

Comment: i tried DeviceAdminReceiver , but it doesn't trigger the password failed/successful method.